# How to extend class custom module Magento 1 which is already overrided

Tags: php, magento

Im trying to add new rows into the Invoice screen, so i have created a new custom module for Magento 1.8.

Added on:

```
class Myname_Module_Block_Adminhtml_Sales_Invoice_Grid extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Invoice_Grid
```

So i placed into the folder the Grid.php file, i have added the following:

```
$this->addColumn('my_custom', array(
            'header'    => Mage::helper('customer')->__('My Custom'),
            'index'     => 'my_custom',
            'type'      => 'currency',
            'align'     => 'right',
            'currency'  => 'order_currency_code',
        ));
```

The problem is, there is another module using this class and extending the same Mage Grid, so on my end im getting: Fatal error: Class 'Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Invoice_Grid' not found in

On my config:

```
<adminhtml>
                <rewrite>
                    <sales_invoice_grid>Myname_Module_Block_Adminhtml_Sales_Invoice_Grid</sales_invoice_grid>
                </rewrite>
            </adminhtml>
```

Any ideas how to extend this class on my module too without loosing the other one? I can not disable the other one.

Answer (score 0):

I got this working, you need to add this

On etc/modules/Myname_Module.xml

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <Myname_Module>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
            <depends>
                <Myother_Module/>
            </depends>
        </Myname_Module>
    </modules>
</config>
```

And then the class needs to be extended to the other module main class :)